# Stop a runaway launchd process on OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, process, launchd, daemon

I created a launchd .plist file to in order to have a python script run every hour. I ended up editing and later deleting the .plist file ( in /Library/LaunchDaemons )... but somehow launchd is still trying to run the script.. The file that the original .plist was calling is also no longer present ( it was in /usr/bin ).. Now every 10 seconds launchd is still attempting to run the script, fails, and respawns...

I tried fixing this with Lingon.... to no avail.. Is there a way to kill this process for good? I tried logging out and restarting as well...

Machine is running 10.5.8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried to run the following?

```
launchctl list  
launchctl stop *label*
```

Comment: I did, and finally doing a   < sudo launchctl remove label >
Killed it for good

Comment: didn't work for me. launchd keeps respawning, I've disabled and stopped and removed and it keeps restarting...