# A process is sending some command to an uninstalled program every ten seconds

Tags: macos, uninstall, console, launchd, steam

A while ago I installed Steam on my Mac... It was a failed attempt as my computer is way too slow to play Portal, so I uninstalled it using AppZapper (I believe). I was doing some computer maintenance and took a look through my logs; I noticed that every ten seconds in console I get this:

**Sender[PID]**

> com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[90]

**Message**

> (com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool[nnn]) posix_spawn("/Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32/ipcserver", ...): No Such File or Directory
>
> (com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool[nnn]) Exited with Code: 1
>
> (com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool) Throttling Respawn: Will start in 10 seconds

Obviously, Steam is still sending some command, but it fails each time as the folder is not there. How can I find where this command is coming from, and how to delete whatever is causing it?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/121355/stop-a-runaway-launchd-process-on-os-x-leopard as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check through this list of directories (see "man launchd.plist"):

```
 ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
 /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
 /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
 /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

You might find some files there related to your steam application.  I hope this points you in the right direction.  I don't know off hand the correct/best way to fix the problem once you find the file(s).

Comment: Yep, this is it! I actually found it myself just a second ago. It was a LaunchDaemon that appzapper failed to delete; deleting it solved the problem.
I also cleaned out a few other obsolete ones that were kickin' around in there.
Cheers!

Comment: To unload/stop a launchd job run `launchctl stop <label>` or `launchctl unload <path to plist>`